# Where can I find alternatives to XAseco?

Tags: trackmania-forever

XAseco is a system that runs alongside a TrackMania server and allows control of the server via chat commands and activities. It's a great system, but it runs on PHP. I'd like to write plugins in C# rather than PHP.

Where can I find alternatives to XAseco, or a full detail of the TrackMania control API?

Comment: This question would probably do better on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Server Fault is not for gaming questions. I've seen game related questions on there and on Stack Overflow get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServerMania?

http://www.tm-forum.com/viewforum.php?f=130